# visual studio workflow error

Tags: solution-package

I developed a .wsp package solution on visual studio  which has a custom list and sequential workflow. 
 When I try to deploy another farm , the list works properly but workflow doesnt appear.

What can be the reason for this, 
Any suggessions?

Comment: Where does it not appear? Is it bound to som specific list?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should [associate workflow with the list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662529%28v=office.14%29.aspx) (Visual Studio does this step behind the scenes when you deploy your project from it, but you need it manually if you use wsp file).

Comment: its not appearing in templates